# Sails.js: How To Access Data in Server-Side EJS View for Single Model

Tags: ejs, sails.js

The Sails.js Wiki clearly describes how to loop through an array of models and generate HTML. See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/wiki/views. However it is not clear to me how to get at the model for a **details** view.

Given a model generated via the shell command: `sails generate user`, there will be these routes:

```
/user
/user/:id
```

(Here `:id` is a token replaced with the unique id of the model. For more details see http://sailsjs.org/#documentation/routes.)

The wiki's example handles the first route, `/user`, but what happens when you go to `/user/:id`--how do you get at the model from the EJS view?

I would expect something like `<%= model.propertyName %>` would work.

Bare in mind I'm asking about generating the HTML **on the server**. (I know how to get the data and render client-side.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create controller action that matches the route and manually pass found model to the view.

In UserController:

```
find: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({'id': req.params['id']}, function(err, user) {
        res.view({user: user})
    })
}
```

Then You can reference this model in views/user/find.ejs:

```
<%- user.id %>
<%- user.name %>
```

Comment: While I agree this should work, my expectation is I should have access to the model (somehow) without writing a custom controller action. It seems like a design goal of Sails is to just have things work assuming you follow the proper conventions. In other words, if you can't get the model for a single item without writing a custom controller action, then that feels like a bug in Sails.

Comment: As we can see from sails docs, resourceful routes behave as follows: 
If the requested controller/action doesn't exist, Sails will try to render appropriate view. If no view present, Sails will respond with JSON API for the model which matches controller. 
So,

Comment: And, as I can see from source code of Sails, the controller **hook**, that serves the JSON API, will query model for requested instances _only_ in case there's no explicit controller action nor view present. So, if you have EJS views, you have to write controller actions explicitly. It's not a bug. But I think, it would be good feature proposition for Sails team.

Comment: But you don't have to write controller actions explicitly for the other HTTP verbs. You can create views for GET (many), POST, PUT, and DELETE actions out-of-the-box without touching the controller. It's just the GET (one) that doesn't seem to work. That's why I think it's a bug in Sails.

Comment: I've created an issue for this with Sails team. See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/646.